# String comparison not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration

I am trying an if else condition in powershell using string comparison. I tried as per documentation using -eq operator. But getting below error. Here "Build.Reason" is a predefined variable. Not sure why its looking for cmdlet name for variable.

```
  Write-Host "$(Build.Reason)"
  if ($(Build.Reason) -eq "Manual" ) {
      $temp = "https://url/api/qualitygates/project_status?&pullRequest=$(Build.Reason)"
      Write-Host "Manual"
  } else {
      Write-Host "CI"
  }
```

Error

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\d7af16d6-ce3e-4dec-a636-9447962fdac4.ps1'"
Manual
Manual : The term 'Manual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\_temp\d7af16d6-ce3e-4dec-a636-9447962fdac4.ps1:7 char:5
+ if (Manual -eq "Manual" ) {
+     ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Manual:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `$(Build.Reason)` is a *macro*-style value provide by a CI system (it is *not* a PowerShell construct), which is expanded to become a *literal* part of the code *before* PowerShell sees it.

Therefore, if this value is to be treated as a *string* in the resulting PowerShell code, you need to *quote* it; e.g.:

```
if ("$(Build.Reason)" -eq "Manual") { # ...
```

Note that if there's a chance that `$(Build.Reason)` expands to a value with *embedded* `"` characters, they would have to be escaped as `` `" ``. Similarly, if the value contains embedded `$` chars., *single*-quoting should be used, which may then require escaping embedded single quotes as `''`.

If this escaping cannot be performed at the *source*, you can use a verbatim [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings):

```
if (@'
$(Build.Reason)
'@ -eq 'Manual') { # ...
```

**Important**: The closing `'@` must always be at the *very beginning of the line*.